# Angular Material MatChipsModule styling horizontally

Tags: css, angular-material

How would I override the css styles for Angular Material's MatChipsModule?

I've tried overriding the default class:

```
.mat-mdc-chip-set-stacked {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

And adding inline styles:

```
<mat-chip-listbox class="mat-mdc-chip-set-stacked" aria-label="Color selection" style="display: flex;">
  <mat-chip-option *ngFor="let chip of categories" [color]="chip.color">
    {{ chip.name }}
  </mat-chip-option>
</mat-chip-listbox>
```

But it isn't changing, is it possible?